# Нехватка памяти при работе с WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, хостинг

При работе с `WordPress` я получил такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /home/alex90/public_html/wp-admin/menu.php on line 224.
```

Что это означает и сколько же памяти обычно требует для работы `WordPress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну что означает - из ошибки видно - памяти скрипту для выполнения не хватило.
Вообще вот эти 34M - мало для цмс-ок и вообще для современного времени. Для друпал 7 например не стоит даже пробовать брать хостинг с лимитом меньше 64. Для wordpress увы по цифрам не в курсе.
Попробуйте у хостера спросить - возможно в настройках удастся увеличить этот показатель.